# Syntax error in converting arrays to JSON arrays and create table

Tags: html, arrays, json

I have an array of arrays of the following type which is actually very very long:

`[["Vishnu", 25],["Joginder", 22],["Amar", 27],["Rohan", 24],["Karan", 23]]`

I first convert them to JSON arrays of the following type:

```
[
  {
    "Player": "Vishnu",
    "Age": 25
  },
  {
    "Player": "Joginder",
    "Age": 22
  },
  {
    "Player": "Amar",
    "Age": 27
  },
  {
    "Player": "Rohan",
    "Age": 24
  },
  {
    "Player": "Karan",
    "Age": 23
  }
]
```

I want to create tables with the help of the asynchronous call d3.json, as the arrays are on another url. I made the following Javascript code

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
    arrayjson = function(ele)
{
  var item = ele;
  return {"player":item[0], "age": item[1]};
}

d3.json('json.html', function (error, data){
           var json_data;
           if(error) { alert(error);visualizeit();}

           data.map(arrayjson);  


function tabulate(data, columns) {

        var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
        var thead = table.append('thead')
        var tbody = table.append('tbody');

        // append the header row
        thead.append('tr')
          .selectAll('th')
          .data(columns).enter()
          .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('tr');

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
          .data(function (row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
              return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
          })
          .enter()
          .append('td')
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; });

      return table;
    }

    // render the table(s)
    tabulate(data, ['player', 'age']); // 2 column table

});
```

and the following

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="c3.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='pdisb.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to figure out where I made the mistake. Any suggestion would be appreciated. It says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://datatables.net/

Comment: @Rob: Sorry, I couldn't get you. I want to create tables with information on other url.